# VS Code Docker DevContainer with MonoRepo

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I'm trying to create a single git repository with 2 python projects in it that share some of the configuration.
Specifically I'm trying to share the `docker-compose.yaml`.

The dir structrure is as following:

```
root
|
- docker-compose.yaml
+-P1
  + .devcontainer
    - devcontainer.json
    - docker-compose.yml
+-P2
  + .devcontainer
    - devcontainer.json
    - docker-compose.yml
```

Each of the `devcontainer.json` has the following in it:

```
    "dockerComposeFile": [
        "../../docker-compose.yaml",
        "docker-compose.yml"
    ],
```

When I try to open each of `P1` or `P2` in DevContainer I'm getting the following error:
[image]

Any idea if that configuration is supported?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the error itself came from having a wrong path to environment variable file in `docker-compose.yaml` file.
And that [VS Code does support mono repo](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/change-default-source-mount).

Comment: How do one use dev containers in a monorepo? Do you open each project in its own vs code window? And do one have to use the built-in terminal? I prefer having VS Code open at root and my own terminal.